# Joomla update mysql query with Cron Job

Tags: joomla, cron, joomla2.5, cron-task

I am not very familiar with Cron Job in Joomla. I have created custom component from [component creator](http://www.component-creator.com/).
I have created two field 1. Title and 2.Cron. Now I want to disable that title when Cron(Date field) and current date is match.

I will thankful If anyone can help me.

Thanks,
Manan

[image]

Comment: Can you post the php for the title field that is displayed?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just make the <a ></a> conditional like in all the other managers?  I mean it would be diffeent in that the if () is based on time not permission but it's just a simple control structure in the tmpl file.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in the component controller file in the controller frontend
let say  myCornTask

let say your component name is com_myform

so modify frontend controller file like this

```
<?php
class MyFormController extends JController{

    public function myCornTask(){

        $app=JFactory::getApplication();
        $today=date('Y-m-d');
        $db=JFactory::getDBO();
        $query="UPDATE `#__my_form_table` SET `state`=0 WHERE `date`='$today'";
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $db->query();
        $app->close();
    }
}
?>
```

/**
 * Activate Corn JOB From CPANEL
 */
Set Corn JOB Once in a day and URL will be

http://yoursite.com/index.php?option=com_myform&task=myCornTask

problem in understanding please reply